# How to make a multiple variable array without a data base in c

Tags: c, arrays

I was given an assignment in my C class, which asks:

> Create an array which will contain personal data of 100 students.

Those data must be:

- last name
- name
- age
- grade in C language
- grade in Java
- grade in C++

Note 1: Every student's data must be saved in a multi-dimensional array, in which every line of the array refers to a particular student and every array column refers to its corresponding data (last name, name, etc.)

I was asked to do this without creating a database.

Is there a way to create a multivariable array using pointers?(and not using struct)

Comment: Καλημέρα, welcome to SO! It's difficult to help with this question because there are things missing that are only obvious to you right now. It's impossible to say if the "array is correct" -- a data structure is not (in)correct in a vacuum. You don't show any relevant code, and you don't mention *how* you think it might be wrong or not. You need to a) scope down the question (it's too broad right now) and b) be *way* more precise and forthcoming with relevant information; you will get much better results asking if you do this. Cheers!

Comment: How about making an array of a struct containing all the individual fields?

Comment: _"The program runs but probably has a logical problem."_ What program? Where is the code? What problem? Why do you think that? I'm voting to close this question as incomplete and vague. SO isn't a place that does your assignments for you; it can help with specific questions, but you have no such thing here. Also: _"The last name must be unique."_ => YAIT.

Comment: _"but windows displays error!"_ Again, please read the Help Centre about how to ask a useful question. There is no point telling readers that you get an error without specifying **what** error: quote it in full. And again, include the full - but minimal - code in your question that readers can use to understand what you're doing and try it themselves. The Help Centre will show you what is expected, i.e. to create an MCVE.

Comment: Sorry! I made edits.Thanks for helping!

Comment: So now there's **no** code & the Q is too broad; SO is not a code-writing service. Also, this is an awful assignment for a teacher to give, as it implies that strings, numbers (age), & grades (which should probably be a number or enum) should all be stuffed in an array of `char*` (or worse, `void*`) & so lose proper typing or require tedious & dangerous acrobatics to get the right value from that degraded form. Why a teacher would tell you not to use `struct`, one of the key features of the language, in exchange for the mess that would result from this... is completely beyond me. Again, YAIT.

Comment: What is a _"multivariable array"_?

Comment: you can use this kind of [crappy code](https://git.geekwu.org/snippets/1) ... but @Lanting answer is far better

Answer (score 3):

`C` doesn't really have multidimensional arrays, but you can have arrays of arrays, arrays of pointers or arrays of structs.

All elements in an array, however, have to be of the same type. So you cannot store a both a name (c string) and mark (integer or double) in the same array.

The usual C approach is to create a structure containing all the fields, and store those in a single top level array:

```
typedef struct Student_ student;
struct Student_
{
  char firstName[20]; //make sure the names aren't longer than 19 chars (use strlcpy!!!), or use char* and malloc for the names!
  char lastName[20];
  double cppMark;
  double javaMark;
  double cMark;
};
Student students[100];
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but i must not use struct!!!

Comment: @ΔΗΜΟΚΡΑΤΗΣ Include such essential info in your question so people don't waste their time.

Comment: edited. I am sorry I am new to this!